# Replacing a table load function with a luigi task

Tags: python, luigi

I have a python  function that loads the data into a sql server table from 2 other tables.

```
def load_table(date1,date2):
    strDate1 = date1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    strDate2 = date2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    stmt = "insert into Agent_Queue (ID)  select distinct Send_Location_ID from Pretty_Txns where Send_Date >= '%s' and Send_Date <= '%s' and Send_Location_ID is not null union select distinct Pay_Location_ID  from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date >= '%s' and Pay_Date <= '%s' and Pay_Location_ID is not null" % (strDate1,strDate2,strDate1,strDate2)
    cnx1= connection string
    self.curs=cnx1.cursor()
    self.curs.execute(stmt)
    self.curs.commit()
```

I am trying to convert this function into a luigi task

Tried the below approach by following the docs:

```
class Datetask(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.DateParameter()

class loading(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return {'date1': DateTask(dt.date(2016,10,30)), 'date2': DateTask(dt.date(2016,11,29))}

    def run(self):
       date1 = dict['date1']

    date2 = dict['date2']
    strDate1 = date1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    strDate2 = date2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    stmt = "insert into Agent_Queue (ID)  select distinct Send_Location_ID from Pretty_Txns where Send_Date >= '%s' and Send_Date <= '%s' and Send_Location_ID is not null union select distinct Pay_Location_ID  from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date >= '%s' and Pay_Date <= '%s' and Pay_Location_ID is not null" % (strDate1,strDate2,strDate1,strDate2)
    curs=cnx1.cursor()
    curs.execute(stmt)
    curs.commit()
    curs.close()
```

When I try and run this , I get errors:

```
    python -m luigi --module load_task loading  --local-scheduler
    DEBUG: Checking if loading() is complete
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi/worker.py:305: UserWarning: Task loading() without outputs has no custom complete() method
  is_complete = task.complete()
WARNING: Will not run loading() or any dependencies due to error in deps() method:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 697, in _add
    deps = task.deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi/task.py", line 572, in deps
    return flatten(self._requires())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi/task.py", line 544, in _requires
    return flatten(self.requires())  # base impl
  File "load_task.py", line 19, in requires
    return {'date1': DateTask(dt.date(2016,10,30)), 'date2': DateTask(dt.date(2016,11,29))}
NameError: global name 'DateTask' is not defined
```

I am defining **DateTask** so the error is confusing me.

Also, do all the tasks need to have all 3 **requires()**,**run**,**output**?

Also, is it necessary to always write the **output** to a file?
Brand new when it comes to using luIgi so would appreciate any inputs

Comment: you have a typo in your task class definition: it should be `DateTask` instead of `Datetask` (t must be uppercase!)

Comment: Besides that, the method output from DateTask must return a subclass of `luigi.Target` instead of a parameter.

Comment: ohh..typo was stupid..and I did read about using luigi.Target to write it to some text file locally. There is no other way to access the date1 and date2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would work better:

```
class LoadTask(luigi.Task):
    date1 = luigi.DateParameter()
    date2 = luigi.DateParameter()        

    def requires(self):
        return None

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("{0}-{1}.txt".format(self.date1, self.date2))

    def run(self):
        strDate1 = self.date1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        strDate2 = self.date2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        stmt = "insert into Agent_Queue (ID)  select distinct Send_Location_ID from Pretty_Txns where Send_Date >= '%s' and Send_Date <= '%s' and Send_Location_ID is not null union select distinct Pay_Location_ID  from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date >= '%s' and Pay_Date <= '%s' and Pay_Location_ID is not null" % (strDate1,strDate2,strDate1,strDate2)
        curs=cnx1.cursor()
        curs.execute(stmt)
        curs.commit()
        curs.close()
        with self.output().open('w') as out_file:
            print >> out_file, strDate1, strDate2
```

Invoke with:

```
luigi --module load_task LoadTask --date1 2017-01-01 --date2 2017-01-02 --local-scheduler
```

> Also, do all the tasks need to have all 3 requires(),run,output?

Yes. Although there are task types, such as `luigi.WrapperTask` that do not require `output()` and you can return `None` from `requires()` if you are the first task in the chain, etc.

> Also, is it necessary to always write the output to a file?

No. For example the SQL Alchemy contrib module defines a Target subclass you can use as a target in the database.
http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.contrib.sqla.html